# REST API for main page - one JSON or many?

Tags: spring, rest, api, architecture, server

I'm providing RESTful API to my (JS) client from (Java Spring) server.
Main site page contains a number of logical blocks (news, last comments, some trending stuff), each of them has a corresponding entity on server. Which way is a right one to go, handle one request like

```
/api/main_page/   ->
{
  news: {...}
  comments: {...}
  ...  
}
```

or let the client do a few requests like

```
/api/news/
/api/comments/
...
```

I know in general it's better to have one large request/response, but is this an answer to this situation as well?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/274340 This may help out

Comment: So one or many? As I said, I know general answer, but it's not perfectly clear for me for this specific situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in general multiple requests can be justified, when the requested resources reflect parts of the system state. (my personal rule of thumb, still WIP).

i.e. if a `news` gets displayed in your client application a lot, I would request it once and reuse it wherever I can. If you aggregate here, you would need to request for it later, maybe some of them never get actually displayed, and you have some magic to do if the representation of a `news` differs in the aggregation and `/news/{id}`-resource.
This approach would increase communication if the page gets loaded for the first time, but decrease communication throughout your client application the longer it runs.
The state on the server gets copied request by request to your client or updated when needed (Etags, last-modified, etc.).

In your example it looks like `/news` and `/comments` are some sort of *latest* or *since last visit*, but not *all*.
If this is true, I would design them to be a resurce as well, like `/comments/latest` or similar.
But in any case I would them only have self-links to the `/news/{id}` or `/comments/{id}` respectively. Then you would have a request to `/comments/latest`, what results in a list of `news`-self-links, for what I would start a request only if I don't already have that `news` (maybe I want to check if the cached copy is still up to date).

It is also possible to trigger the request to a `/news/{id}` only if it gets actually displayed (scrolling, swiping).

Probably the lifespan of a `news` or a `comment` is a criterion to answer this question. Meaning the caching in the client it is not that vital to the system, in opposite of a `book` in an Book store app.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should have different API calls for fetching individual configurable content blocks of the page from the same API.

- This way your content blocks are loosely bounded to each other.
- You
  can extend, port(to a new framework) and modify them independently at
  anytime you want.
  This comes extremely useful when application grows.
- Switching off a feature is fairly easy in this
  case.
- A/B testing is also easy in this case.
- Writing automation is
  also very easy.
- Overall it helps in reducing the testing efforts.

But if you really want to fetch this in one call. Then you should add additional params in request and when the server sees that additional param it adds the additional independent JSON in the response by calling it's own method from BL layer.

And, if speed is your concern then try caching these calls on server for some time(depends on the type of application).